# How to emit signal when scrollbar is moved in scrollview

Tags: qml

Is there any signal which get emitted when scrollbar moved in the scrollview or else please help me to emit the signal when scrollbar moved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your question as written does not appear to be related to an issue with the Ubuntu OS. I'd suggest that you ask your question over on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead. Best of luck!